# How to preload information on my Swift app/project by using userDefaults command

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

Good day, i am sending this question because i need help on SWIFT programming. I am working on a SWIFT project and I am looking there is one command to save information on device, "userDefaults" command, I need to add, i am using that command to allow end users to save some information entered in one window/form. My question, would you please let me know if i could pre-save or pre-load some saved information on my app, i am looking the userDefaults command creates a .plist document and there is all information saved (inside AppData/Library/preferences/. The purpose of this app is to capture some data but i want to show old data pre-loaded as soon the app is installed on iphone.

Today i am doing this trick but its taking too much time on Archive process even when my app it 5 mg data.

Trick ,

I am creating some functions like below:

```
    func preLoadInfo001() {
    preLoadInfo.append(["Number": "0001", "Day": "26", "Month": "9", "Year": "2023", "Data1": "1", "Data2": "2", "Data3": "2500", "Data4": "2700", "Data5": "2800", ])
    .
    .
    .
    preLoadInfo.append(["Number": "0200", "Day": "30", "Month": "9", "Year": "2023", "Data1": "10", "Data2": "20", "Data3": "2500", "Data40": "2700", "Data50": "28000", ])
    }

    func preLoadInfo002() {
    preLoadInfo.append(["Number": "0001", "Day": "26", "Month": "9", "Year": "2023", "Data1": "1", "Data2": "2", "Data3": "2500", "Data4": "2700", "Data5": "2800", ])
    .
    .
    .
    preLoadInfo.append(["Number": "0200", "Day": "30", "Month": "9", "Year": "2023", "Data1": "10", "Data2": "20", "Data3": "2500", "Data40": "2700", "Data50": "28000", ])
    }

    func preLoadInfo003() {
    preLoadInfo.append(["Number": "0001", "Day": "26", "Month": "9", "Year": "2023", "Data1": "1", "Data2": "2", "Data3": "2500", "Data4": "2700", "Data5": "2800", ])
    .
    .
    .
    preLoadInfo.append(["Number": "0200", "Day": "30", "Month": "9", "Year": "2023", "Data1": "10", "Data2": "20", "Data3": "2500", "Data40": "2700", "Data50": "28000", ])
    }
```

I am having like 10 functions like this and i also created a button (that end user needs to hit to preload all information as soon as the installation is completed) with this function.

```
`func preLOAD(){
func preLoadInfo001()
func preLoadInfo002()
func preLoadInfo003()
.
.
.
func preLoadInfo020()

// Save all information on device
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(mainInformation, forKey: "SavedInformation")
} // Save all information needed to use this app. `
```

My question is: Would you please let me know if exist a way to storage all this information on my App and as soon as end user installs the app then the .plist is created with all old information instead to request end user to push the button that is writing all information on device?

I do not know if a plist needs to be created with all old information and then find a way to install that on my final package app, or if i need to create an specific file , install that file on muy SWIFT project and then call that file as soon as end user open the app for first time.

Thank you in advance for all support.

I am expecting to know if exist a way to preload some information on my app package and then access all information by using userDefault command.

Comment: UserDefaults is not the proper place to save data. It's only means to store simple little values like preferences and options. There are plenty of discussions about various data storage options.

Comment: Preloading data with all those functions is not a good approach.
 Don't use that, and don't use UserDefaults as already mentioned.
 You could put all your data that needs pre-loading into an internal file and read that
 from within your App. Lots of info on how to save and pre-load data on SO and the net,
for example look up [SwiftData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata)

Comment: Just a quick qustion, would you please let me know which is the risk that exist on using userDefaults to manage a large amount of data? I need to add that i am using an array of directories recorded on userDefaults and my app still working properly, i have added around 2800 registres ... would you please let me know if my app could get broken?

Comment: UserDefaults is the most insecure and unstable storage don’t use it for anything important.